# How to confirm a powder is Sodium Hydroxide?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry

Long-story-short, my mother found a bag of white powder with some soap making supplies.  We're about 90% sure it's powdered lye, but I thought it would be fun to confirm this somehow.

Is there a way to do so using easily-sourced supplies?  A simple pH test would at least confirm it's caustic, and I've read burning the powder might indicate the sodium content, but I'm not sure what else might help.  Thanks!

Comment: If it is a bag that has been sitting on a shelf for a long while, then its contents is most likely not sodium hydroxide anymore, even if it was initially.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Why, in a tightly closed plastic bag NaOH is going to be just fine.

Comment: If it had been kept sealed for all these years and then cut open just now, then sure, it may still be fine.

Comment: Ift it was perfectly sealed it might be NaOH. If it has alcaline reaction,  it yellows even a stove flame, and it shows deliquescency then you are almost sure it is.

Comment: It could be also anhydrous sodium carbonate, even if the decahydrate is more common as the washing soda. It is also possible it got dehydrated in dry air. I would try an acid test, .e.g. with vinegar, how much CO2 is released.

Answer (score 0):

Tests for sodium hydroxide:

1. Do a pH test. Sodium Hydroxide is basic.
2. Do the [flame test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_test). A bright yellow flame shows that sodium ions are present.
3. A few drops of dilute sodium hydroxide solution react to form a white precipitate with aluminium ions, calcium ions and magnesium ions. However, in excess sodium hydroxide solution

   1. The aluminium hydroxide precipitate dissolves to form a colourless solution
   2. The calcium hydroxide precipitate is unchanged
   3. The magnesium hydroxide solution is unchanged

Adapted from [[1]](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-test-for-sodium-hydroxide) and [[2]](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zxtvw6f/revision/2#:%7E:text=A%20few%20drops%20of%20dilute,to%20form%20a%20colourless%20solution).

Comment: Quora is as good as a source just as a sieve is good as a container for water. Judging from how broad the answer is, I'm pretty confident you could cite any introductory analytical chemistry textbook instead.

Comment: @andselisk I've added info and a more reputable source.

Comment: I never heard of BBC Bitesize, but [BBC as news network has horrible reputation](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.bbc.co.uk), especially after NPC journalism episodes. Maybe I'm too old, but I don't see how either Quora or bbc.co.uk can be a reputable source.

Comment: @andselisk I'm in the UK where the BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation) is based, and BBC bitesize is a well-known and well-recommended resource to help students revise for exams.

Comment: Not all food that is easy to digest and is widely recommended is good for you. Same goes with online studying platforms. Maybe the material is good, maybe not. No way to tell for sure in the absence of transparent referencing, peer reviews and editorial board consisting of the specialists in the field.